# How can I get my asynchronous url images loaded into NSMutableArray in order?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am trying to load images by their URL and store them in NSMutableArray **in order**. My current code works properly if I were not to care about storing the images in order, however it stores them not in order. It currently stores the images in the **articleImage** array based on the speed at which the asynchronous requests are completed. I have tried playing around with insertObject:AtIndex but could not get anything to work. To clarify, the NSMutableArray that I am trying to store the images in (in orderly fashion) is **articleImage**.

**Here is some code from my viewDidLoad:**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    if(articleInfoJSONArray.count > 0)
                    {
                        for(int i=0; i<articleInfoJSONArray.count; i++)
                        {
                            [issueID addObject:[[articleInfoJSONArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"issueID"]];
                            [articleID addObject:[[articleInfoJSONArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"articleID"]];


                            NSString *imageLink = [[articleInfoJSONArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"articleImage"];

                            dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

                            dispatch_async(queue, ^{

                                NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageLink]];
                                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                                    [articleImage addObject:image];
                                    if(articleImage.count == articleInfoJSONArray.count)
                                        [self imagesLoaded];
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    }                        
                });
```

**Here is my imagesLoaded:**

```
- (void)imagesLoaded
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    ViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainView"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Without looking at the code the words "asynchronous" and "order" seem mutually-exclusive.

Comment: Hopefully that is not the case :(

Comment: Again, without looking at the code, I can think of 2 solutions: 1. One background thread loading the images sequentially. 2. Associate an index number with each job and use that to store the images in their array.  1 is better as it's simpler and will likely run just as quickly.

Comment: The 2nd is what I initially tried but I couldn't figure out how to do it =/

Comment: Use the first. It's simple.

Comment: If you use AFNetworking then you can assign a userInfo object to each request and then compare userInfo in success block to see which request completed.

Answer (score 0):

One way i did an image download is with NSOperationQueue and NSOperation. You could define a NSOperationQueue in your header file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSOperationQueue *sequentialOperationQueue;
```

in your implementation do:

```
self.sequentialOperationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
self.sequentialOperationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
```

then you can add:

```
for (NSDictionary *imageDict in imagesToFetch) {
    ImageDownloadOperation *imgDownloadOperation = [[ImageDownloadOperation alloc] initWithImageLocationDict:imageDict];
    [self.sequentialOperationQueue addOperation:imgDownloadOperation];
}
```

LogoDownloadOperation is a subclass of NSOperation. this way you always have only one active download and process them in the order you want. For details on NSOperation check the apple doc.

in extract i did in ImageDownloadOperation:

```
- (void)start {
    NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:self.imageDict[@"imageUrl"]];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadPhotoTask = [session
                                               downloadTaskWithURL:imageUrl
                                               completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                                   if (error) {
                                                       self.sessionTask = nil;


                                                       [self done];


                                                       return;
                                                   }




                                                   NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location];
                                                   NSBlockOperation *saveImageBlockOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
                                                       [SharedAppDelegate.entityManager saveImage:imageData
                                                                                            imageDict:self.imageDict
                                                                                  inManagedObjectContext:SharedAppDelegate.managedObjectContext];
                                                   }];
                                                   saveImageBlockOperation.qualityOfService = NSQualityOfServiceBackground;
                                                   [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:saveImageBlockOperation];


                                                   [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
                                                   self.sessionTask = nil;
                                                   [self done];
                                               }];


    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
}
```

As you can see, i store the imageData via my AppDelegate in CoreData. Instead of my way, you could give the ImageDownloadOperation a pointer to your NSMutableArray, then you can store the data direct in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use dispatch_group. A dispatch group monitors work that has been added to it, and it will know when that work is done. :) http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/

Comment: Rather than posting links, please explain how can this be achieved, since in the future, the link might break.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an array of `[UIImage new]` then once the task is complete
replace the empty image  `images[i] = newImage`

EDIT

```
NSMutableArray *imageArray = [NSMutableArray new];

for (int i=0; i<articleInfoJSONArray.count; i++) {
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage new]];
}

for (int i=0; i<articleInfoJSONArray.count; i++) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //download image
        imageArray[i] = downloadedImage;
    });
}
```